# fetch within loop, how to access loop counter

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am attempting to use fetch inside a loop (something like the pseudo code below) and I know that the responses may come back in a different order to that in which they were asked. That would be fine so long as I know what the value of ctr was when the fetch request was originally made but I can not fathom a way of getting that information passed from the original fetch call to the processing of the response.

All the example snippets I see about using fetch in loops seem to suggest that you add commands to wait for each fetch call to finish before doing the next one but I presume this would be slower (correct me if you think I'm wrong in that regard).

```
for (let ctr = 0;ctr < 10;ctr++)
{
    fetch(URL_OF_SOME_API,fetch_options)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(function (data_returned_by_API)
    {
        // do something with data_returned_by_API and ctr
    });
}
```

Comment: You have access to `ctr` inside the `.then` callback.

Comment: would that be the ctr as it was at the time of the original fetch?

Comment: Yes, it will be.

Comment: This question got marked as a duplicate of a previous question but I noticed the old question was asked nearly 14 years ago and has 44 answers! and the top answer has a highly upvoted comment "Unfortunately, this answer is outdated and nobody will see the correct answer at the bottom". There is also a highly upvoted comment saying "In ES6, a trivial solution is to declare the variable i with let". What's more, if someone is not familiar with the concept of "closure" (and I wasn't) then they will have a hard time finding that other question. Maybe it is time for a fresh question and answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code already works as intended because of how `let` works when its variable is used in closures.

```js
const sleep = (ms) =>
  new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(ms), ms));


for (let ctr = 0; ctr < 10; ctr++) {
  sleep(Math.random() * 5000 + 1000)
    .then(function(data_returned_by_API) {
      console.log(ctr, data_returned_by_API);
    });
}
```

`var` doesn't work

```js
const sleep = (ms) =>
  new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(ms), ms));


for (var ctr = 0; ctr < 10; ctr++) {
  sleep(Math.random() * 5000 + 1000)
    .then(function(data_returned_by_API) {
      console.log(ctr, data_returned_by_API);
    });
}
```

For more information, you can check out [What is the difference between "let" and "var"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/762011/12101554)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the internal of the loop inside of an IIFE passing in `ctr` as an argument, e.g.:

```js
for (let ctr = 0; ctr < 10; ctr++)
{
    ((ctr) => {
        setTimeout(() => { console.log({ctr}) }, Math.random() * 1000)
    })(ctr);
}
```

Or, you can use `Promise.all`, like this:

```js
let i = 0;
let p = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
    let j = i++;
    setTimeout(() => { resolve(j); }, Math.random() * 1000);
})


let promises = [];
for (let ctr = 0;ctr < 10;ctr++)
{
    promises.push(p())
}

Promise.all(promises).then((res) => console.log(res));
```